# Python putting all words on same line

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to remove some words (located on a text file) on another text file. Although my code seems to work, I noticed that it stopped removing words at a certain point in the text file. I then checked the text file, and noticed that Python is writing all the words on the same line, and this line has a limit of characters to it, resulting in the process stopping. How can I circumvent that?

Here is my code:

```
# text file list to array

with open('function_words.txt') as functionFile:
    functionWords = [word for line in functionFile for word in line.split()]

# delete the word on the text file if it matches one of the array

with open("results.txt", "r+") as newfile: 
    newfile.write(' '.join(i for i in toPrint.read().split() if i not in functionWords))
```

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: join with `\n` instead of a space?

Comment: @Sayse that puts every word on a new line, which is not what i'm trying to do neither :(

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do, trying to do it with comprehensions is probably making this alot harder for you than it needs to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to put the "\n" after you join the string if you want each line separate in the new file. Note the `+ "\n"` below.

```
with open("results.txt", "r+") as newfile: 
    newfile.write(' '.join(i for i in toPrint.read().split() if i not in functionWords)+ "\n")
```

alt. you could create a list of the lines you want to write and write `newFile` using the `writelines()` methods. Something like:

```
newFile.writelines(my_list_of_lines_to_write)
```